# Nautilus sort order with ls

Tags: nautilus, ls

I am creating image sprites and have neatly named around 100 files. I am using the following to generate an image sprite from individual images:

```
convert $(ls -w 1000) +append sprite.png
```

I have just noticed that Nautilus 3.4.2 sorts by name differently from `ls`.

Is there a way to get `ls` to use the same ordering as Nautilus (and not the other way around)?

**Example**

Nautilus order:

- cloudy_with_heavy_rain.png
- cloudy_with_heavy_rain_night.png

`ls` order:

- cloudy_with_heavy_rain_night.png
- cloudy_with_heavy_rain.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well this drove me mad for five minutes. Change your statement to:

```
convert $(LC_COLLATE="C" ls -w 1000) +append sprite.png
```

For some reason Nautilus doesn't follow the system-wide locale settings so sorts are out of sync. By faking back to the standard, sorts unify.

---

My test harness:

```
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ touch cloudy_with_heavy_rain{,_night}.png

$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oli oli 0 Apr 13 00:32 cloudy_with_heavy_rain_night.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oli oli 0 Apr 13 00:32 cloudy_with_heavy_rain.png

$ LC_COLLATE="C" ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oli oli 0 Apr 13 00:32 cloudy_with_heavy_rain.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oli oli 0 Apr 13 00:32 cloudy_with_heavy_rain_night.png
```

Comment: Excellent. That sorts it :)