# How to name a file to be the very first in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, unicode, filename, ascii, file-sorting

New versions of Nautilus are cool, because they skip nonalphanumeric letters at the beginning of any file name and sort files according to the first alphanumeric letter (if any). But how to name a file in order to sort it before `0`? Assume I have a folder with these files:

```
0apple.conf
apricot.xml
banana
camel.so
cat.py
dog.tar.bz
```

and I want to add a one or two letter prefix to the `cat.py` in order to sort it before `0apple.conf` file. I don't want to change the name, just add a prefix. I also don't want to change others' names. I've already tried:

1. `#cat.py` and `.cat.py` names and Greek alphabet prefixes sort file to the end (after
   `dog.tar.bz` file; `.` changes also visibility)
2. any of `,-";:-–\_(?)*+%=<>!` prefixes sorts the file between `camel.so` and `dog.tar.bz` (like without any prefix).

Yes, there is an option to add more zeros to be near the beginning, but I want the file name as shortest as possible and at the very first position.

PS: My language is czech (therefore the collation should be something like `cs`, `cz`, `czech` or `cs_CZ`).

Comment: See this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169472/sorting-lists-when-there-are-no-leading-zeros   && this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/sorting-filenames-numerically-when-they-have-non-numeric-prefix  && this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/list-files-sorted-numerically

Comment: @Aurigae sorry, but these are not related, they sort them only in ls, but not in Nautilus

Comment: and `+0cat.py`?

Comment: Nope, still not first

Comment: One answer can be found at this link: [Nautilus Guide](http://www.subdude-site.com/WebPages_Local/RefInfo/Computer/Linux/LinuxGuidesByBlaze/Nautilus_Guide/NautilusGuideBlaze.htm#grp_NautilusSort) under the heading "Nautilus Sort". It's a way of changing the way Nautilus handles special characters when sorting filenames.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prefix `0` already makes the file to be sorted at very first in Nautilus. What can come before the very first file? No files could, except directories. This is true regardless of locale in use.

### File naming

In the following example, I first created an empty text file named `apple.txt` then made multiple copies and rename each of the files by adding single character prefix. I have used only most compatible alphanumeric characters: `0 A á _ -` and  (space). This means I have created 7 files in total, plus a directory named `apple` for reference.

Note that `á` is the second letter of Czech, which is found in [this article section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_orthography#Alphabet) on Wikipedia. The first letter seems to be same as English: `A` and `a`.

### File sorting

How will Nautilus sort these files in different locale environment? Turns out that it is similar but slightly different. See the following screenshot for comparison.

[image: Nautilus in English and Czech environment]

Nautilus sorted files in English environment `en_US.UTF-8` like this:

```
apple <-- directory
0apple.txt
Aapple.txt
áapple.txt
apple.txt <-- original file without prefix
 apple.txt
_apple.txt
-apple.txt
```

Nautilus sorted files in Czech environment `cs_CZ.UTF-8` like this:

```
apple <-- directory
0apple.txt
Aapple.txt
áapple.txt
 apple.txt
apple.txt <-- original file without prefix
-apple.txt
_apple.txt
```

In both locales, there is no change in order of directory and top 3 files when viewing as list in Nautilus. This already shows that no alphanumeric character can appear before `0apple.txt`.

### Workaround 1

One way is to create files with name other than existing "apple" with same prefix `0` that precedes the existing one. Creating `0aaa.txt` will come before `0apple.txt` and so forth.

Using this workaround, the files are sorted like this:

```
0.txt
0a.txt
0aaa.txt
0apple.txt
...
```

This way, the file `0.txt` would be the very first file to appear in Nautilus. No other files can come before `0.txt`, unless user want to create a file name `.txt` (using only a space character).

### Workaround 2

Say if `apple` is already the very first file that can exist and user insists to *not* rename `apple`, there is another way: Rename the existing file with higher number prefix from `0apple.txt` to `9apple.txt`. This will allow other files with lower number prefix `0*` to `8*` to appear before `9apple.txt`.

Using this workaround, the files are sorted like this:

```
0mango.txt
1kiwi.txt
2orange.txt
...
9apple.txt
...
```

Workaround 2 is unsuitable, if the `0apple.txt` as whole cannot be renamed for whatever reason. Workaround 1 will be more effective since `0.txt` will always appear before `0mango.txt` or other file names that user can think of.

### How did I test

In my testing, only essential locale packages were installed to prepare Czech environment for running Nautilus in Ubuntu. The quick way to run program in other locale by `LANG=<LOCALENAME> nautilus` command didn't work. Hence, the following steps.

- Install these packages `language-pack-gnome-cs language-pack-gnome-cs-base language-pack-cs language-pack-cs-base` via APT in Terminal
- Go to **System Settings > Language and Support**
- In **Language - Language for menus and windows**, drag the entry named `čeština` (word for "Czech" [noted by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_language)) to above `English`
- Log out and log in again to take effect

Tested using Nautilus 3.14.3 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Live).

**TL;DR** Filename with prefix `0` makes the very first file in Nautilus. No other files, except directories can appear before the very first file.

Comment: Regarding Nautilus sorting behaviour insanity and disrespect against environmental variable, refer to [this older post](http://askubuntu.com/q/281726/37165).

Comment: As a native Czech person, I must correct you: `Á` or `á` is the second letter in the Czech alphabet after `A` or `a`. Look at the left column in the linked Wikipedia table. The right column is spelling of the letter in the left column.

Comment: @Melebius Corrected accordingly. My bad, I had misread in "Name" column instead of "Letter" in the table.

Comment: Another minor thing is that `Á` or `á` is not the same as `A` or `a`. But you answerred most of my question, thanks

Comment: I intended to use a letter from Czech that may supercede typical roman letters or even numbers, but I misread the table on Wikipedia. I'm ashamed of my silly mistake... I haven't tried with other locale, though.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried space zero as a prefix?

[ 0cat.py]

The other characters you mentioned does not work for me too but space zero works fine.

You can also try other combinations of spacial chars and zero, things like: -0cat.pay, _0cat.py, etc. these should work too.

Comment: Cool, but is this good if I want to operate with that file using terminal?

Comment: I think I should encode the filename and the autocomplete wouldn't work, which is not so convenient.

Comment: I also can not rename any file to this name in Nautilus (I can do this only with terminal), which is also not so convenient.

Comment: Try another combination of spacial chars and zero, something like -0cat.py or !0cat.py or anything else, these should work too. I edited my answer.

Comment: For me not, 00apple.conf is still before -0cat.py :/

Comment: The space trick doesn't work either, " 0cat.py" is still after 00apple.conf

Comment: What is  your nautilus version?

Comment: 3.20.1 (fully updated, the last one available)

Comment: @aleskva If all non-alphanumeric symbols in the beginning of the filename are ignored, the rest are sorted according their positions in character map, where all numbers have the precedence. So you won't find other way than add more leading zeros to move your file to the top. Sort order is also impacted by `$LC_COLLATE` variable. You can find some info [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35469) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/877731).

Comment: I don't know if all, that's why I ask

Comment: @aleskva Have you tried `_0cat.py`? It works for me in 3.10.1.

Comment: Tried, not working